# Se me cambio el valor de operador logico el or por el and en javascript

Tags: javascript, html5, array, operador, lógica

Se me cambio el valor de operador lógico el `or` por el `and` en javascript estoy usando `atom.io` y he intentado de todo. Borrar el código, cambiar las variables del array, etc... Pero no me funciona, lo único que se es que el navegador chrome, como internet explorer me toma que el operador logico `or` (||) me lo toma por un `and` (&&)

### Este es el código del script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var pregunta1 = prompt("eres de argentina");
var repuesta = ["si", "Si"];
if (pregunta1 == repuesta[0||1])
{
  alert("bien");
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

No está bien escrito el código la condición tendría que ser

```
pregunta1 == repuesta[0] || pregunta1 == repuesta[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

podrías usar este código el cual coloca las letras todas en minúsculas de esa manera no deberás verificar en la opción que coloque con mayúsculas o no.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var pregunta1 = prompt("eres de argentina");
    pregunta1 = pregunta1.toLowerCase();

    if (pregunta1 == "si")
    {
      alert("bien");
    }
</script>
```

en este caso .toLowerCase() colocara todo tu texto en minúsculas :) ojala te sirva